# Comparing Doubles and Chars in C++

Tags: c++, char, double

I am trying to write a simple program in C++ that reads in an unspecified number of marks, then once the user inputs the character 'q', the program must calculate and display the average mark. However I am having some trouble. The approach I am taking is to save each value as a double, the I want to compare the double to the character 'q' and if they are the same character, end the loop, calculate and display the average.

However I think that the comparison between the `char` value 'q' and `double` value for the mark seem to be incomparable. This worked for me when I did the same using integer values for the mark but not doubles it seems. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
int main()
{
    cout << "Please enter any number of marks. Enter 'q' to stop." << endl;
    double total = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    bool repeat = true;
    do
    {
        double mark;
        cin >> mark;

        if (mark != 'q')
        {
            total += mark;
            counter++;
        }
        else
        {
            repeat = false;
        }

    }
    while (repeat == true);

    double average = total/counter;
    cout << "Average: " << average << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Really not my preferred solution, but you can do `if (std::cin.peek() == 'q')` before reading the mark.

Comment: Cool, thanks. If that isn't your preferred solution what would you recommend?

Comment: @chris I think you should post it as answer, such a case is the purpose for the existence of this method (istream::peek).

Comment: Read the string first, Compare it to q. Then convert the string into a double if it is not q. atof(aString.c_str())

Comment: @Cthulhu, It's quick, but it misses quite a few possible opportunities to catch errors. For example, leading whitespace (including a leftover newline) isn't discarded, and typing `quick` will count as a q. Reading strings is really probably the best way to be sure you're getting what you want.

Comment: `int` or `double`: if you input to it, and the user enters `q`, the stream enters an error state.  (And since you don't verify that the input worked, your code will then go into an endless loop.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can not cast a double to char. You may need to use additional c++ library functions which convert string (char*) to double. There are different ways to do this.
    Try this :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << "Please enter any number of marks. Enter 'q' to stop." << endl;
    double total = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    bool repeat = true;
    do
    {
        char userinput[8];
        cin >> userinput;


    std::stringstream ss;
    double mark;

        if (userinput[0] != 'q')
        {
            ss << userinput;
            ss >> mark;
            total += mark;
            counter++;
        }
        else
        {
            repeat = false;
        }

    }
    while (repeat == true);

    double average = total/counter;
    cout << "total : " << total  << " count : " << counter << endl;
    cout << "Average: " << average << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I used stringstream and it worked very well.

Answer (score 2):

you'll need to change the mark variable to string, and then compare it to 'q', else try to parse is as a number.

otherwise this entire code, does not make a lot of sense, because 'q' in ASCII is 113, which I guess is a possible value

Comment: I realise that, but I was thinking a mark between 0 and 100. Any ways, how would you recommend I go about parsing to a number?

Comment: @JamesAllingham, `std::stod` if you have it.

Comment: you'll need to do some sanity test before, but in general, you can use

"atoi( str.c_str());"

Comment: please note that "atoi" will return the number till the parse has failed, for example "100Rg32" will return 100

Answer (score 2):

Typecast double to int and then compare, It must work because it compares ASCII value of character

Here is the code:

```
 int main()
{
cout << "Please enter any number of marks. Enter 'q' to stop." << endl;
double total = 0;
int counter = 0;
bool repeat = true;
do
{
    double mark;
    cin >> mark;

    if ((int)mark != 'q')
    {
        total += mark;
        counter++;
    }
    else
    {
        repeat = false;
    }

}
while (repeat == true);

double average = total/counter;
cout << "Average: " << average << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong. If you try to `cin` a `char` into a `double` variable, the input `char` stays in the input buffer and the `double` variable remains the same. So this will end in an infinite loop.

If you really want the user to enter a `char` to end input, you need to take the whole input in a string variable. Check the string for `q`. If not present, use [atof()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atof/) to convert it to double.